# AngularJS: Can I make div/span elements change form's ng-valid status?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form. Inside that form, I have a dropdown that adds items to an array in the model. Inside the ng-repeat for that array, there is a list of requirements that the model needs before it can be considered valid, which is displayed in `<span>` elements. That list is checked with a function that is run by ng-class in order to display the requirement as green or red depending on whether the requirement has been met. I need the form to be considered invalid when any of these items are red. I have tried returning ng-invalid in the class of the `<span>` element along with the class that sets the color, but the form ignores this. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Could you post your code here so that we can figure out the problem?

Comment: Not easily, but I have a solution now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the validation variables directly on you controller. So you can do a function to verify any modifications and set the form validity as you want.

Some code example:
The form should be invalid if the input is empty, but this can be override by the checkbox value.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ctrl);

function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.chkChange = function(value) {
    $scope.form.$valid = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="form">
    <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkbox" ng-change="chkChange(chkbox)">
  </form>
  <p>Form valid {{form.$valid}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Interesting that changing $valid to false doesn't change $invalid.